# Listview margin and padding in ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I am trying in vain to add a padding and margin to my list view in a List fragment, but it seems to ignore all parameter, no matter where i put id. How do i work around it? Am using a custom adapter

this is my R.layout.list_boomark

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Description"
        android:id="@+id/textView_desc"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"/>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Chapter information"
            android:id="@+id/textView_chapter"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:textColor="#999"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time Stamp"
            android:id="@+id/textView_offset"
           android:textColor="#888"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time Stamp"
            android:id="@+id/textView_timestamp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColor="#888"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you using custom adapter if yes then you need to add margins to the inflated view

Comment: yes i am using a custom adapter

Comment: show xml code of custom adapter layout file

Comment: the only layout i included in my custom adapter is the layout for each item, all the same i included the adapter code

Comment: I asked for xml code of R.layout.list_bookmarks view.

Comment: but why are you using `0dp` in all your padding and margin properties?

Comment: not all of them, they are used in the various text views to remove spacing between the text views. i want to add a margin to the whole view to prevent it from being on the edge of the screen

Comment: @KiddBuBu sorry my fault. just use padding for root layout. margin is used for inner views of root view ..

Answer (score 1):

For the root layout you need to provide **android:padding** and not **android:margin**.

**Margin** defines extra space on the sides for external views(for root view there are no sides).

**Padding** it is the space between a view and its content.

Answer (score 0):

IN Relative layout just give padding=10dp